# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I know this has been discusses at least a million times here but every servlet was redirecting or flushing the output before calling forward(). I have the same problem but I am not doing anything with the output. My servlet just takes the request parameters and commits to the database and sets an attribute on the request. Then, it forwards the request to a jsp which them displays the attribute. I am using Servlet 3.0 on Tomcat 7. Here is my servlet doPost method followed byt the jsp that this is forwarding to:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);

        DAOFactory daoFactory = DAOFactory.getFactory();
        daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().beginTransaction();

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setName(req.getParameter("companyName"));
        company.setContactEmail(req.getParameter("companyEmail"));
        company.setContactPhone(new Long(req.getParameter("companyMobile")));
        company.setAddressLine1(req.getParameter("companyAddressLine1"));
        company.setAddressLine2(req.getParameter("companyAddressLine2"));
        company.setCity(req.getParameter("companyCity"));
        company.setZipcode(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("companyZip")));
        company.setState(req.getParameter("companyState"));     
        company = daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().save(company);
        daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().commitTransaction();

        Employee owner = new Employee();
        owner.setFirstname(req.getParameter("ownerFirstName"));
        owner.setLastname(req.getParameter("ownerLastName"));
        owner.setEmail(req.getParameter("ownerEmail"));
        owner.setMobileNum(new Long(req.getParameter("ownerCellPhone")));
        owner.setZipcode(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("ownerZip")));
        owner.setRole("Employer");
        owner.setCompany(company);
        daoFactory.getEmployeeDAO().beginTransaction();
        owner = daoFactory.getEmployeeDAO().save(owner);
        daoFactory.getEmployeeDAO().commitTransaction();

        company.addEmployee(owner);
        company.setOwnerId(owner.getId());

        daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().beginTransaction();
        company = daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().save(company);
        daoFactory.getCompanyDAO().commitTransaction();

        req.setAttribute("company", company);
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/companyConfirmation.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);

    }
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>The Company was saved successfully</h3>
<p>
Company name: ${company.name}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure I may have missed something very trivial. I cannot figure out what it is especially when I am not writing anything to the output before forwarding the request.

PS: I also tried putting a `return;` statement after the forward but no change.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code that's being executed by super.doPost()?

Comment: It was super.doPost() that was causing the problem. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the `super.doPost(req, resp)` method call. The default implementation of  doPost method from HTTPServlet returns HTTP 405 status code meaning "Method not supported" and that's the response which has been committed. Therefore, you can not forward your request to other jsp.

This is part of the `RequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp)` method description: "forward should be called before the response has been committed to the client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response already has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. Uncommitted output in the response buffer is automatically cleared before the forward".